# Can I decrease the time taken to delete Firebase projects?

Tags: firebase

Firebase projects take about a month to be completely deleted. In that time, the project still counts towards a user's project quota. I foolishly created a bunch to test different aspects of Firebase instead of creating a single project to recycle for playing around.

Is there a way to reduce the time until I can create more projects? I feel that requesting an increase is a waste of Firebase administration staff time as I do not NEED them, I'm just an idiot ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force it.  [Contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/) for help, or simply use a different Google account to keep experimenting with Firebase and Google Cloud.

In the future, you can effectively and immediately free up a spot for another unpaid project by simply adding billing to a existing unpaid project.  If that project isn't consuming any resources, then you won't be billed anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response @doug-stevenson. I've already converted the remaining projects to the Blaze PAYG plan, but that does not seem to have freed any spots in my unpaid project quota. I did this over 24 hours ago for one project. What is the average expected time for this to take effect?